# Стиль кода useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

С помощью useState происходит рендринг чтобы поменялось значение на странице, везде вижу, что используют только тип данных const и меняют значение вот так`setCount(count+1);` Можно ли использовать, let при создание useState и менять так `count+=1;setCount(count+1);` ? или так не рекомендовано?

```
  let [count,setCount]=useState(0)
  const [count,setCount]=useState(0)
```

Comment: А в доках не написано? Если нет, то не значимо (очень маловероятно)

Comment: Не просто "не рекомендовано" - состояние нельзя изменять напрямую https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: так получается, могу переменную изменить саму, count+=1;setCount(count); а потом её отправить в состояние

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного сумбурно получилось...

Можно использовать конструкцию

```
let [a, setAa] = React.useState(0);
a++;
```

Нам это никто не запрещает, особенно, что мы можем это сделать. Только это не приведет к изменению самого состояния. 
Да, можно сделать так:

```
let [a, setAa] = React.useState(0);
a++;
setA(a);
```

**НО!** Это не рекомендовано и даже не правильно, однако, да, можно так сделать :)

`const` используют для того, что бы уберечь себя от случайного изменения данных.

Однако есть Объекты. **React** это все тот же **javaScript** и **useState** возвращает не склонированный объект, а ссылку на него, поэтому можно "неумышленно" изменить состоние компонента.

```
const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ a: 5 });
obj.c = 'new';
```

Теперь и в компоненте `obj` и в состоянии одни и те же данные, однако, такое изменение не вызовет ререндер компонента, так как передается ссылка на тот же объект и при сравнении, старые данные и новые будут равны. Такого поведения стоит избегать.

```
const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ a: 5 });
obj.c = 'new';
setObj(obj); // не вызовет повтоный рендеринг
```

Для возможности повторного рендера при работе с объектами, лучше использовать **spread** оператор

```
const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ a: 5 });
obj.c = 'new';
setObj({ ...obj }); // вызовет повтоный рендеринг
```

Ниже полный код с приведенными выше примерами:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);

const ObjChange = () => {
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ a: 5 });
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([1, 2]);
  
  const changeObj = () => {
    obj.b = obj.b ? ++obj.b : 1;
    setObj(obj);
    arr.push(3);
    setArr(arr);
  };

  const changeObjUpd = () => {
    obj.b = obj.b ? ++obj.b : 1;
    setObj({ ...obj });
    arr.push(3);
    setArr([...arr]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Текущее состояние объекта: {obj.a} {obj.b}
      <br />
      Текущее состояние массива: {arr.map((i) => i)}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => changeObj()}>Поменять данные</button>
      <button onClick={() => changeObjUpd()}>Поменять данные и обновить</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  let [a, Sa] = React.useState(0);
  console.log("Begin", a);
  a++;
  a++;
  a++;
  a++;
  console.log("End", a);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        a: {a} 
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            Sa((e) => {
              console.log("Current", e);
              return e + 10;
            })
          }
        >
          Прибавить 10
        </button>
      </h1>
      <hr />
      <ObjChange />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Поиграться [можно здесь](https://codesandbox.io/s/statechange-d1emsh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к предыдущему ответу.

`setState(count + 1)` - так не рекомендуется делать.

`setState((currentCount) => currentCount + 1)` используйте коллбэк, чтобы избежать нечто похожего на гонку данных, в том случае, если событие, вызывающее `setState()`, будет слишком быстро срабатывать (к примеру, очень быстро кликать на кнопку, которая меняет счетчик).